# ComputerBrowser service is missing in Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm using Windows Server 2012 to manage my network domain. The problem is that the ComputerBrowser service is missing in my services list. How can I reinstall or repair it?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you disable SMBv1, or remove the client for Microsoft network Windows feature?